# How can I add a notification minutes before alarm?

Tags: android, notifications

Im developing an android app where the user sets an alarm.I have already made a notification if the user has missed the alarm but im find it confusing on adding notification atleast 10mins before alarm. Can anyone help me with this? Here is my code for the missed alarm:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification;
PendingIntent activity;
Intent intent;

Log.i(TAG, "AlarmNotification.addNotification(" + alarm.getId() + ", '" + alarm.getTitle() + "', '" + mDateTime.formatDetails(alarm) + "')");

intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AlarmMe.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int)alarm.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notification = builder
    .setContentIntent(activity)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle("Missed alarm: " + alarm.getTitle())
    .setContentText(mDateTime.formatDetails(alarm))
    .build();

notificationManager.notify((int)alarm.getId(), notification);
```

and the Alarm.Java

```js
package com.example.guest.remindme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Alarm implements Comparable<Alarm>
{
  private Context mContext;
  private long mId;
  private String mTitle;
  private long mDate;
  private boolean mEnabled;
  private int mOccurence;
  private int mDays;
  private long mNextOccurence;

  public static final int ONCE = 0;
  public static final int WEEKLY = 1;

  public static final int NEVER = 0;
  public static final int EVERY_DAY = 0x7f;

  public Alarm(Context context)
  {
    mContext = context;
    mId = 0;
    mTitle = "";
    mDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mEnabled = true;
    mOccurence = ONCE;
    mDays = EVERY_DAY;
    update();
  }

  public long getId()
  {
    return mId;
  }

  public void setId(long id)
  {
    mId = id;
  }

  public String getTitle()
  {
    return mTitle;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title)
  {
    mTitle = title;
  }

  public int getOccurence()
  {
    return mOccurence;
  }

  public void setOccurence(int occurence)
  {
    mOccurence = occurence;
    update();
  }

  public long getDate()
  {
    return mDate;
  }

  public void setDate(long date)
  {
    mDate = date;
    update();
  }

  public boolean getEnabled()
  {
    return mEnabled;
  }

  public void setEnabled(boolean enabled)
  {
    mEnabled = enabled;
  }

  public int getDays()
  {
    return mDays;
  }

  public void setDays(int days)
  {
    mDays = days;
    update();
  }

  public long getNextOccurence()
  {
    return mNextOccurence;
  }

  public boolean getOutdated()
  {
    return mNextOccurence < System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public int compareTo(Alarm aThat)
  {
    final long thisNext = getNextOccurence();
    final long thatNext = aThat.getNextOccurence();
    final int BEFORE = -1;
    final int EQUAL = 0;
    final int AFTER = 1;

    if (this == aThat)
      return EQUAL;

    if (thisNext > thatNext)
      return AFTER;
    else if (thisNext < thatNext)
      return BEFORE;
    else
      return EQUAL;
  }

  public void update()
  {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (mOccurence == WEEKLY)
    {
      Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();

      alarm.setTimeInMillis(mDate);
      alarm.set(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

      if (mDays != NEVER)
      {
        while (true)
        {
          int day = (alarm.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 5) % 7;

          if (alarm.getTimeInMillis() > now.getTimeInMillis() && (mDays & (1 << day)) > 0)
            break;

          alarm.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        alarm.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
      }

      mNextOccurence = alarm.getTimeInMillis();
    }
    else
    {
      mNextOccurence = mDate;
    }

    mDate = mNextOccurence;
  }

  public void toIntent(Intent intent)
  {
    intent.putExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.id", mId);
    intent.putExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.title", mTitle);
    intent.putExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.date", mDate);
    intent.putExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.alarm", mEnabled);
    intent.putExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.occurence", mOccurence);
    intent.putExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.days", mDays);
  }

  public void fromIntent(Intent intent)
  {
    mId = intent.getLongExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.id", 0);
    mTitle = intent.getStringExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.title");
    mDate = intent.getLongExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.date", 0);
    mEnabled = intent.getBooleanExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.alarm", true);
    mOccurence = intent.getIntExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.occurence", 0);
    mDays = intent.getIntExtra("com.taradov.alarmme.days", 0);
    update();
  }

  public void serialize(DataOutputStream dos) throws IOException
  {
    dos.writeLong(mId);
    dos.writeUTF(mTitle);
    dos.writeLong(mDate);
    dos.writeBoolean(mEnabled);
    dos.writeInt(mOccurence);
    dos.writeInt(mDays);
  }
 
  public void deserialize(DataInputStream dis) throws IOException
  {
    mId = dis.readLong();
    mTitle = dis.readUTF();
    mDate = dis.readLong();
    mEnabled = dis.readBoolean();
    mOccurence = dis.readInt();
    mDays = dis.readInt();
    update();
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't read through your code, it's really long. Wouldn't this just be as simple as making an 'alarm for your alarm'? If you already know how to make something happen at time T, you should be able to make something happen at time T-10.

Comment: The answer is 2 alarms.  One to set the notification, one to do whatever the current alarm does.